# Symfony2 format error when setting date with DateTime

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I have date values that I need to insert to my database.
If I try to add a simple string:

```
$user->setUpdatedAt('2015-05-31 05:46:23')
```

ofc i get error, that the value has to be a DateTime object.

So i create the datetime object:

```
$user->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime($row[29]))
```

This creates:

```
object(DateTime)[1052]
  public 'date' => string '2015-05-31 05:46:23' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

But when I try to flush I get:

> Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Why does it not see that its an object, when it clearly is?

UPDATE:

The entity class i a simple FOSUser generated entity:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 */
protected $updatedAt;

/**
 * Sets the last update date.
 *
 * @param \DateTime|null $updatedAt
 *
 * @return User
 */
public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt = null)
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Returns the last update date.
 *
 * @return \DateTime|null
 */
public function getUpdatedAt()
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

/**
 * Hook on pre-persist operations.
 */
public function prePersist()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
}
```

Comment: Show us code of your entity class.

Comment: @AlokPatel I updated my question

Comment: Where is `setUpdatedAt()` method?

Comment: @AlokPatel Sorry, updated

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine's date types convert incoming values (DateTime objects, of course if you set field type as date, datetime, datetimetz) to string, and convert them back to DateTime object when it fetches from db. Try to find the right class (DateTimeType.php, DateTimeTzType.php, DateType.php, based on your mapping type) and debug the `convertToDatabaseValue` method (e.g: `dump($value);die();`), check what value is coming. Or use xdebug, debug from your setter to `convertToDatabaseValue` method.

Comment: Hello, the problem is, that the value is null and it does not format.. I dont understand why..

Comment: @Dominykas55 It's being overridden somewhere in your code then. I recommend you to use xdebug to find out where.